# C++ cannot read from 2D string array

Tags: c++, arrays

this cold be really obvious but I havent done C++ in about 15 years so thanks in advance.
I have a 2D array of strings and when I read from it I get this:
0x22fc90

Here is my code, any ideas?

```
std::string results[3][3] = {  
                 {"Draw", "Win", "Lose"} ,   /*  initializers for row indexed by 0 */
                 {"Lose", "Draw", "Win"} ,   /*  initializers for row indexed by 1 */
                 {"Win", "Lose", "Draw"}   /*  initializers for row indexed by 2 */
                };
cout << "It's a " << results[choice,compChoice];
```

choice and compChoice are integers

Comment: `results[choice][compChoice]`.

Comment: It should be results[choice][compChoice]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between for example the C++ syntax and the C# syntax for multidimensional arrays. What you wrote in this statement relative to accessing an element of the array

```
cout << "It's a " << results[choice,compChoice];
```

is valid in C# and does what you mean.

In C++ this statement

```
cout << "It's a " << results[choice,compChoice];
```

is also valid but its meaning is different. There is used the so-called comma operator in the subscript operator `results[choice,compChoice]` that in fact is equivalent to `results[compChoice]` except that the first subexpression will not be evaluated. So `results[compChoice]` gives a row of the two-dimensional array and `operator<<` outputs its address.

What you want is the following

```
cout << "It's a " << results[choice][compChoice];
```

Answer (score 1):

Access the array using `results[choice][compChoice]`.

That's because two dimensional arrays are actually arrays of arrays.

First you need to go into `results[choice]` and then you select `[compChoice]` from that.

Answer (score 1):

`choice,compChoice` just evaluates to `compChoice`, so you are just outputting the pointer to the start of the `choice`th array in `results`. Use `results[choice][compChoice]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

results is an array of arrays. Try accessing via

```
results[choice][compChoice]
```

So results[choice] "returns" an array that you can access with another [] operator. As far as I know, multiple indices aren't supported in one pair of brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.Am glad it was a syntax issue am not me missing the point completely!